# Is there anyway to use different version of xamarin forms within a solution?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having 2 solutions with the following structure

```
solution 1
   SharedProj (netstandard2.0)
   App1.NetStandard2.0
   App1.Droid
   App1.IOS
Solution 2
  SharedProj (netstandard2.0)
   App2.NetStandard2.0
   App2.Droid
   App2.IOS
```

so as shown above SharedProj i am sharing common code between 2 apps. All projects in both solutions have xamarin forms nuget installed and I am using currently 2.5 version of xamarin forms on both projects and it works fine but I want to use 3.0 pre version on App2 projects and here is the problem starts. 
I am getting error message that `"Xamarin.Forms tasks do not match targets. Please ensure that all projects reference the same version of Xamarin.Forms, and if the error persists, please restart the IDE."` I understand that it is because now SharedProj has different version on one of the solution.

Xamarin forms was allowing to use different versions of different project in same solution in earlier versions. now they return error after 2.3 version I believe. Is there anyway to suppress this error or is it not safe at all?

Comment: not safe at all.

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks for confirming. i was just wondering because before 2.3 version, this was no problem happening and was allowed. this is added later. It is obvious that it is the problem between 3 and 2.5 as it is totally new version but is it also a problem between 2.4 and 2.5 for example? how realistic is to user v3 pre in production? as far as I tested, i couldnt find a significant bug.

Comment: It is really never "ok" to substitute assemblies from different versions, but that is a different story.... Using v3-pre in production, that is solely your call, v3 is a huge re-do for Forms, breaking APIs, renderer rework, etc..personally I've worked on projects that had such a comprehensive testing suite for app functionality and device compatibly (we were testing on 300+ unique devices on each commit) that I would do it if the tests passed, other apps, no way in h3ll as the test cover within the app itself and across devices was so lacking I would not risk a public release, so your call ;-)